# Hibernation doesn't work in Debian Wheezy (suspend does work)

Tags: debian, drivers, hibernate

Recently I've been trying to make hibernation work. Suspending works all the time, so "hibernate/suspend debug tutorials" didn't helped me much. The only one that gave me some information about the problem was this one: www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt

I learned that problem occurs with "devices" and so it might be some driver that messes around. But then lsmod displays a lot of modules and many of them are "in use" and I cannot just unload then and test.

Is there some easier way to get rid of a problem? Maybe there are some known problems with some drivers?

---

- dmesg from what should be waking from hibernation: http://pastebin.com/MCXU5wPA
- lsmod: http://pastebin.com/rHMnzTN9

Configuration:

- CPU: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T8300 @ 2.40GHz × 2,
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV730,
- RAM: 8GB,
- SWAP partition: 8GB as well,
- OS: Debian Wheezy 3.2.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 28 09:07:26 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with newer versions of drivers for the graphic card.

For the time being I switched to proprietary AMD drivers. It solved problem with hibernation but, at least in my case, AMD's proprietary drivers were more problematic (manual reinstallation after each kernel update) and had worse performance. After a while I gave free drivers another chance and previous problem disappeared.

My guess is that was some error in free drivers that got repaired in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

My problem and solution is similar as yours.
Problem:
hibernate well but hung when restore

Solution I install fglrx-driver FGLRX / AMD Catalyst is the non-free proprietary display driver for the ATI/AMD RadeonHD and FireGL graphics cards.
during installation it asked you to renew your xorg.conf. As root run this

```
$ aticonfig --initial
```

But I recognize there's noticeable downgrade performance